# Difference between X3D and X3DV files

Tags: java, x3d

I'm wondering what's the difference between an X3D file and an X3DV file.

I'm creating an application in Java that loads and displays an X3DV file called `test.x3dv` and I have multiple X3D models that I want to be loaded and I'm using Xj3D.

However, it only want's to load X3DV models. So I was wondering what the differences are, so that I can change the X3D files I have round to be X3DV files.

Answer (score 1):

`.x3d` is the extension for the [XML Encoding](http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19776-1/V3.3/Part01/X3D_XML.html) of X3D whereas `.x3dv` is the extension for the [Classic Encoding](http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19776-2/V3.0/Part02/conformance.html) of X3D (which is pretty much like VRML).

They both describe X3D scenegraphs, so yes, you can use whichever encoding is more convenient for you.

---

For example, here's a Shape in X3D (XML Encoding):

```
<Shape>
    <Appearance>
        <Material diffuseColor='0 1 0'>
        </Material>
    </Appearance>
    <Box>
    </Box>
</Shape>
```

And the same shape in X3D (Classic Encoding):

```
Shape {
    appearance Appearance {
        material Material {
            diffuseColor 0 1 0
        }
    }
    geometry Box {}
}
```